# Novel where everyone has to wear masks. Boy time-travels and experiences anti-Semitism

Tags: story-identification

This was a novel I read in the 2000s (in middle school).

- It was set in the future.
- Everyone had an opposite gender twin that was their life partner.
- A major plot point is everyone wears masks.
- A boy went back in time and experienced anti-Semitism.

Answer (score 7):

Could this be [*The Cure*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/452356.The_Cure) by Sonia Levitin?

> "You are a criminal, Gemm 16884--aggressive, hostile, nonconforming.
> We have noted tendencies toward diversity in your gait, in your
> dreams, and most especially in your repeated persistence in"--the
> Elder cleared his throat--"making music."
>
> Branded a deviant--and therefore a threat--to the utopian society of
> Conformity, Harmony, and Tranquility that exists in the year 2407,
> Gemm 16884 is given the choice between being recycled or undergoing a
> painful and mysterious cure. Gemm chooses the cure, and suddenly finds
> himself living the life of Johannes, a 16-year-old Jewish musician in
> starsbourg, Germany, in 1348, at the onset of the Black Death. As the
> pestilence spreads, the townspeople begin to accuse the Jews of
> causing the disease. Surrounded by hatred and horror, Johannes
> struggles to hold on to his family and faith as well as his belief in
> the basic goodness of human beings. But can he return to the future
> and become Gemm again after having known such emotions as pain. . .and
> love?
>
> [image]

Multiple reviews mention masks, twins, anti-Semitism and time travel.